# How to read stream of JSON objects per object

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonstream

I have a binary application which generates a continuous stream of json objects (not an array of json objects). Json object can sometimes span multiple lines (still being a valid json object but prettified).

I can connect to this stream and read it without problems like:

```
var child = require('child_process').spawn('binary', ['arg','arg']);

child.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Streams are buffers and emit data events whenever they please, therefore I played with readline module in order to parse the buffers into lines and it works (I'm able to JSON.parse() the line) for Json objects which don't span on multiple lines.

Optimal solution would be to listen on events which return single json object, something like:

```
child.on('json', object => {
   
});
```

I have noticed objectMode option in streams node documentation however I' getting a stream in Buffer format so I believe I'm unable to use it.

Had a look at npm at pixl-json-stream, json-stream but in my opinion none of these fit the purpose. There is clarinet-object-stream but it would require to build the json object from ground up based on the events.

I'm not in control of the json object stream, most of the time one object is on one line, however 10-20% of the time json object is on multiple lines (\n as EOL) without separator between objects. Each new object always starts on a new line.

Sample stream:

```
{ "a": "a", "b":"b" }
{ "a": "x",
  "b": "y", "c": "z"
}
{ "a": "a", "b":"b" }
```

There must be a solution already I'm just missing something obvious. Would rather find appropriate module then to hack with regexp the stream parser to handle this scenario.

Comment: May multiple JSON objects "overlap" in a single line?

Comment: New object always starts in new line as per information above. However the end of the object can be anywhere: just a single closing curly bracket by it's own or right after last value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to try parsing every line:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
 input: child.stdout
});

var tmp = ''
rl.on('line', function(line) {
  tmp += line
  try {
    var obj = JSON.parse(tmp)
    child.emit('json', obj)
    tmp = ''
  } catch(_) {
    // JSON.parse may fail if JSON is not complete yet
  }
})

child.on('json', function(obj) {
  console.log(obj)
})
```

As the child is an EventEmitter, one can just call child.emit('json', obj).

Comment: Funny :) came two identical answer, but your earlier :)

Comment: You need use input instead outptut when create readline interface.

Comment: Thank you :-) didn't think of try{}catch{}

Answer (score 0):

Having the same requirement, I was uncomfortable enforcing a requirement for newlines to support readline, needed to be able to handle starting the read in the middle of a stream (possibly the middle of a JSON document), and didn't like constantly parsing and checking for errors (seemed inefficient).

As such I preferred using the [`clarinet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clarinet) sax parser, collecting the documents as I went and emitting `doc` events once whole JSON documents have been parsed.

I just published this class to NPM

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-doc-stream

Comment: Does this mean you keep the entire document in memory?